# Checking multiple and conditions based on dynamic user input to stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, relational-division

I have a table with data like below,

```
keyId att_id att_value
1     1      4
1     2      5
2     1      4
```

I have my input to a procedure as a json `{"1":"4","2":"5"}`.

My procedure should return me the keyId which has both (att_id = 1 and att_value = 4) and (att_id=2 and att_value=5). So the output of this json input should be only 1 and not 2 as the second key value pair in json is not satisfied. Is there any way to dynamically append the and conditions inside a stored procedure in postgresql.

Comment: And by "procedure" you mean a plpgsql function? Or just an SQL `SELECT` query? Please start by declaring your Postgres version. The input is exactly *two* key/value pairs or a variable number? If so, variable how exactly?

Comment: After extracting the input values from your JSON format, it burns down to a case of relational division. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7828605/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `att_id,att_value` combination per KeyId has no duplicates, you may use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT  KeyID 
 FROM   t 
WHERE  ( att_id, att_value ) IN (SELECT inp.key :: INT, 
                                         inp.VALUE :: INT 
                                  FROM   json_each_text('{"1":"4","2":"5"}') AS 
                                         inp )
 GROUP BY  keyId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=73a5c209b356ad1a72084080dc8078b3)

Comment: No distinct would not work.. This will give me both 1 and 2 in the result set.. In clause is checking for OR clause internally and I need to check whether both the key value pairs are satisfied by a particular key id.

Comment: @SathishKumar : Please check now.